# Stuck on Razor extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

I'm trying to refactor some commonly-used code into a helper extension and am stuck with the syntax, largely because I don't have a full grip of generics, lambda expressions etc.

I'd like to be able to put this in my view, and for it to use my model's field (eg FirstName) to produce some HTML that makes use of other Razor extensions:

```
@MyHelpers.BootstrapFormItem(m => m.FirstName)
```

At the moment I've got:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Linq.Expressions;

@helper BootstrapFormitem(XXXXXXXXX) 
{
         <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(XXXXXXX)
            <div class="controls">
               @Html.DisplayFor(XXXXX)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(XXXX)
            </div>
         </div>
}
```

Questions:

1. Is this the right approach? I'd like to be able to use this method with any viewmodel field.
2. Have I included the right namespaces? This will go in the app_code folder
3. What goes in XXXXXX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class do what you need, I use these all the time:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString BootstrapFormItem<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder("<div class=\"control-group\">");
        html.AppendLine(helper.LabelFor(expression).ToString());
        html.AppendLine("<div class=\"controls\">");
        html.AppendLine(helper.DisplayFor(expression).ToString());
        html.AppendLine(helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString());
        html.AppendLine("</div>");
        html.AppendLine("</div>");
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
    }
}
```

Note that this is a static class and also an extension method, the first input parameter is prefixed with 'this' which means it will extend (show up after you type a '.' in Intellisense) any objects of type `HtmlHelper<TModel>`. I will generally put this class in a *Utilities* folder.  I often use a namespace as well and reference it from the *web.config*.

**EDIT TO ANSWER QUESTIONS:**

Here is the usage, it is covered by Intellisense as well:

```
@model MyClass

@Html.BootstrapFormItem(x => x.Name)
```

This is the output:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        naspinski
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you did this in a class rather than declaratively? I chose to do it declaratively so that I could use the intellisense and razor syntax checker etc.

Comment: Also - could you give an example of usage? The usage I specified above doesn't work because it expects 2 parameters. Many thanks.

Comment: This will use intellisense as well - editing to answer questions.

Comment: This actually only takes one input (expression) the first input is preceded by 'this' meaning it is an extension of the HtmlHelper.  This just makes more sense to me as a class, especially if there are going to be multiple helpers.

Comment: Note that I forgot to make the class static at first, it must be static!